# Can I cancel rebind with special actions like double escape key press in Unity's Input System?

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
void RebindStart(InputAction rebindKey, int bindingIndex, string excludeDevice)
    {
        isRebindDone = false;
        isBusy = true;
        
        string deviceName;
        string controlPath;
        rebindKey.GetBindingDisplayString(bindingIndex, out deviceName, out controlPath);
        beforeBindingPath = "<" + deviceName + ">" + "/" + controlPath;
        var firstPartIndex = bindingIndex + 1;
        if (firstPartIndex < rebindKey.bindings.Count && rebindKey.bindings[firstPartIndex].isPartOfComposite)
            allCompositeParts = true;
        
        rebindKey.Disable();

        
        waitingKeybindingUI.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        rebindingOperation = rebindKey.PerformInteractiveRebinding().WithTargetBinding(bindingIndex)
            .OnMatchWaitForAnother(0.1f)
            .WithControlsExcluding("<Keyboard>/capsLock")
            .WithControlsExcluding("<Keyboard>/leftMeta")
            .WithControlsExcluding("<Keyboard>/contextMenu")
            .WithControlsExcluding("<Keyboard>/numlock")
            .WithControlsExcluding("<Keyboard>/printScreen")
            .WithControlsExcluding("<Keyboard>/scrollLock")
            .WithControlsExcluding("<Keyboard>/pause")
            //.WithCancelingThrough("*/{Cancel}")
           
            
            if(excludeDevice != "")
             rebindingOperation.WithControlsExcluding(excludeDevice);
            
                 rebindingOperation.OnCancel(operation => RebindCancel(rebindKey))
                .OnComplete(operation => RebindEnd(rebindKey, bindingIndex))
                .Start();
            
        
        InputManager.Instance.deviceChangeAction += rebindingOperation.Dispose;
        InputManager.Instance.deviceChangeAction += RestartUI;
        InputManager.Instance.deviceChangeAction += SetEvent;
    }
```

I made rebind functions like this.
In this project's Input Action Map, Cancel Action is designated as Escape Button in Keyboard.
But while building this function, the directed gave me the opinion that can desinate 'ESC' key as other button's key.

But I don't think that is impossible.
So I thought that only one esc key input is rebind at other key
and double esc key input is Cancel.

I'd appreciate it if you could give me a little help or idea even if it's not this way

I have no idea about this.
I tried to find simillar one on Internet, but I didn't find it.